# How to link custom script to spring boot jar?

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

I have created a symlink for a spring boot executable jar and i am able to start the application. I want to customize the logs path, pid folder etc.
Went through the customizing the startup of [this script](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-service).

But I could not find where to store the custom script and how it can be linked to executable application jar. Could you please assist?

Comment: Those are the docs for Spring Boot 1.3.0 snapshots which is rather out of date. What version of Spring Boot are you using? Also, what build system are you using  as that affects how you configure the customisation.

Comment: I am using Spring boot 2.1.0.RELEASE and maven as a build tool. Currently when i start the application using executable jar it is creating a log and pid in var/logs and var/run. I would like to redirect them into custom folder within a linux server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script with name your-app.service, place this script in /etc/systemd/system directory.

**Installation as a systemd Service**, using Java System Properties (VM Arguments):

```
[Unit]
Description= Spring Boot App
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=myapp
ExecStart=java -Dspring.application.name=example -Dlogging.file=/opt/spring-boot-app/log/app.log -Dspring.pid.file=/opt/spring-boot-app/app.pid -jar /opt/spring-boot-app/app.jar
SuccessExitStatus=200

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Or pass throught via program arguments:

```
java -jar /opt/spring-boot-app/app.jar --spring.application.name=example --logging.file=/opt/spring-boot-app/log/app.log --spring.pid.file=/opt/spring-boot-app/app.pid
```

References in [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-initd-service).

> - **logging.file**= # Log file name (for instance, `myapp.log`). Names can
>     be an exact location or relative to the current directory.
> - **spring.pid.file**= # Location of the PID file to write (if
>     ApplicationPidFileWriter is used).